# Painful jquery error with Jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below function erroring and its begin a real pain.

For some reason it is saing postData is not defined on the lines marked with error. But I have defined postData and populated it with the returned json from get.php?? Is there something missing here.

```
<script>
 function postToFeed(shoeID) {

    $.post("get.php",{id: shoeID}, 
                function(data){
                               var postData = data;
                               }, "json");  

    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: postData.title, //ERROR
      caption: '<?=SHARE_CAPTION?>',
      description: postData.description //ERROR
    };

    function callback(response){
        if(response['post_id']){
            $.post("vote.php",{id: '<?=(isset($_POST['fbid'])? $_POST['fbid'] : $data['id'])?>', shoe: shoeID, type: 'share'}, 
                            function(score){
                            $("#shoe_"+shoeID).html(score)
                            }); 
        }
    }

    FB.ui(obj,callback);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe googling _"javascript scope"_ could help you some more.

Comment: Is the call asynchronous? If so, none of the answers actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have defined it inside the success handler of post it is not accessible. Define `postData` in the outer scope it will work fine.

```
function postToFeed(shoeID) {
    var postData;//
    $.post("get.php",{id: shoeID}, 
                function(data){
                               postData = data;
                               }, "json");  

....
....
```

One more thing to note here. You are using `$.post` which makes an `ajax` call asynchronously so even if you define `postData` in the outer scope it will not work because until the post request executes the `postData` is null or empty.

So you should execute rest of the code inside the success handler of `$.post`. Try this.

```
function postToFeed(shoeID) {

    $.post("get.php",{id: shoeID}, function(data){
      var postData = data;
      var obj = {
           method: 'feed',
           link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
           picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
           name: postData.title, //ERROR
           caption: '<?=SHARE_CAPTION?>',
           description: postData.description //ERROR
      };

      function callback(response){
        if(response['post_id']){
            $.post("vote.php",{id: '<?=(isset($_POST['fbid'])? $_POST['fbid'] : $data['id'])?>', shoe: shoeID, type: 'share'}, 
                            function(score){
                            $("#shoe_"+shoeID).html(score)
                            }); 
        }
      }

      FB.ui(obj,callback);

    }, "json"); //$.post-End 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move postData outside the callback so it is accessible inside `obj`..

```
var postData;
$.post("get.php",{id: shoeID}, 
           function(data){
               postData = data;
           }, 
           "json");
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not define it in the inner function, define it outside and only assign the value in that function

```
<script>
var postData;
function postToFeed(shoeID) {


$.post("get.php",{id: shoeID}, 
            function(data){
                             postData = data;
                           }, "json");  

var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: postData.title, //ERROR
  caption: '<?=SHARE_CAPTION?>',
  description: postData.description //ERROR
};

function callback(response){
    if(response['post_id']){
        $.post("vote.php",{id: '<?=(isset($_POST['fbid'])? $_POST['fbid'] : $data['id'])?>', shoe: shoeID, type: 'share'}, 
                        function(score){
                        $("#shoe_"+shoeID).html(score)
                        }); 
    }
}

FB.ui(obj,callback);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rearrange your code a little bit:

```
function postToFeed(shoeID) {
    function callback(response) {
        if (response['post_id']) {
            $.post("vote.php", {
                id: '<?=(isset($_POST['fbid'])? $_POST['fbid'] : $data['id'])?>',
                shoe: shoeID,
                type: 'share'
            }, function(score) {
                $("#shoe_" + shoeID).html(score)
            });
        }
    }

    $.post("get.php", {
        id: shoeID
    }, "json").done(function(postData){
        var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            name: postData.title,
            caption: '<?=SHARE_CAPTION?>',
            description: postData.description
        };
        FB.ui(obj, callback);

    });   
}​
```

Notice how `obj` is built and `FB.ui()` is called only after the original `$.post()` is `done`.